# Can these Xcode Run options be disabled through CMake?

Tags: xcode, cmake

Can the following Xcode Run options be disabled with the use of CMake?

- Allow Location Simulation
- Allow debugging when using document Versions Browser
- Debug XPC services used by this application
- Enable backtrace recording

[image: Xcode Options Page]

Comment: "Can the following XCode Run options be disabled ..." - You image has a tab with **several options**, each one with its own specifics. Which option you want to set via CMake? Please, avoid asking several questions in one post.

Comment: Whoops, sorry! I'm thinking of the ones that are currently checked / enabled